# Library behaviour while migrating from VB6 to VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6-migration

I have a VB6 application which i need to convert to VB.NET 3.5. The application uses a lot of Business objects libraries and some external libraries.
I would like to know if these libraries would behave the same way when i move from VB to VB.net?Are there chances that things would break?Please advice..

Comment: Are you hoping to keep the library code in VB6 and call it from a VB.NET application? Or do you want to migrate the library code to VB.NET as well?

Comment: Yes the library code will still be in VB.Since the libraries are 3rd party we might not have access to the class library code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is it depends.  There should be no issue and I know Microsoft has made a great effort to make sure this type of migration path works, but being third party you never know if something may go wrong.  The only advice I can give is test often and test everything.  If it is possible make a program to just test the functionality of the libraries.  HTH.

Wade